# Override the sort indexes

Tags: javascript, sorting

From a backend, I'm getting items to object with sort indexes (random number between 1 and 999) and item list array with ids of the items sorted by their indexes like:

```
{
    items: {
        1: {
            sort: 131,
            name: 'Item 1'
        },
        2: {
            sort: 22,
            name: 'Item 2'
        },
        3: {
            sort: 440,
            name: 'Item 3'
        },
        4: {
            sort: 80,
            name: 'Item 4'
        }
    },
    itemList: [2, 4, 1, 3]
}
```

Using a UI user can change the order of the element which reflects in the itemList array. After clicking on save button in the UI I need properly reassign existing sort indexes and send to the backend only elements whose index was changed. So for example, if the user set `item 2` to the second position itemsList will be `[4, 2, 1, 3]`, and data sent to the backend should be:

```
{
    2: {
        sort: 80
    },
    4: {
        sort: 22
    }
}
```

If the user set `item 2` to the fourth position itemList will be `[4, 1, 3, 2]`, and data sent to the backend should be:

```
{
    1: {
        sort: 80
    },
    2: {
        sort: 440
    },
    3: {
        sort: 131
    },
    4: {
        sort: 22
    }
}
```

How can I achieve that functionality?

Comment: what is actually not working?

Comment: Why not just have the `itemList` have the items sorted out there? Instead of holding a list of indexes with the sort order.

Comment: As per my understanding, I created getUpdatedItems() method in my answer, where you pass new Items List, which compares with the old itemsList and logs changes the way you need to send to server.. Kindly confirm if this is what is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can achieve it

```
var getUpdatedItems = (function() { 

    var items = {
        1: {
            sort: 131,
            name: 'Item 1'
        },
        2: {
            sort: 22,
            name: 'Item 2'
        },
        3: {
            sort: 440,
            name: 'Item 3'
        },
        4: {
            sort: 80,
            name: 'Item 4'
        }
    },
    itemsList = [];

    function _getUpdatedItems(newItemsList) {
        itemsList = Object.entries(items).sort(([,a], [,b]) => a.sort - b.sort).map(([data]) => data);

        var dataToSend = {};
        newItemsList.forEach((key, index) => key != itemsList[index] && (dataToSend[key] = { sort: items[itemsList[index]].sort }))

        console.log(dataToSend)
    }

    return _getUpdatedItems;

})()

// you can test with below test and you will get expected result
getUpdatedItems([4,2,1,3]) 

getUpdatedItems([4,1,3,2])
```

Comment: Let me know if this is what you are trying to achieve? @bashkovpd

Comment: Yep, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!